# How to sort the array of custom class

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, c#-4.0

I have a custom class

```
public class Student{
    public int start;
    public int end;

    public void SortStudents(Student[] students){
         /*Code to sort the student according to the 'start'*/
    }
}
```

I want to sort this array of students according to the 'start' in C#.

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried so far and why that isn't working?

Comment: Use the Linq OrderBy extension function.

Comment: Also, I suggest writing such functions to take an IEnumerable<T> so that they are more flexible. Good practice for .NET development.

Comment: 1. SortStudents should be static. 2. It's not student's class responsibility to sort array of student. 3. It could implement IComparable, but not sorting. 4. public fields are bad.

Comment: You can implement the interface IComparable containing the method CompareTo(...).

Answer (score 2):

You can sort your array like this.

```
Array.Sort(students, (x, y) => x.start.CompareTo(y.start))
```

+1 to the comments recommending IEnumerable and Linq instead.

Comment: This is the best approach - using methods (`Array.Sort` and `CompareTo`) which has been specially designed for the task (array sorting and integer comparison). -1 for comments recommending IEnumerable and Linq instead (we have an array aleady, why should we step back to `IEnumerable<T>`?)

Comment: I can only comment on my own experiences, but to me it seems like more often than not when you have multiple of a custom object you will want to use IEnumerable<T>, especially when your collection increases in size, you want to do more complex operations on it and/or your custom object's internal handling is getting more complex. However if you only have a small collection with a small scope and simple operations, an array will probably be the more lightweight choice.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the time complexity of this sort?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Student
{
    public int start;
    public int end;

    public void SortStudents(Student[] students)
    {
        Array.Sort(students, (x, y) => x.start - y.start);//asc
        Array.Sort(students, (x, y) => y.start - x.start);//desc
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, you can have an *overflow* (`IntegerOverflowException`) on `x.start - y.start` (if `start` are very large / small); that's why `x.start.CompareTo(y.start)` is the right approach

Comment: This answer needs more explaination about how it works to become a good answer on SO.